# rspec-support showing version issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rubygems

When i try running the spec file of my rails application this error pops up

> Could not find 'rspec-support' (~> 3.9.1) - did find: [rspec-support-3.6.0,rspec-support-3.5.0] (Gem::MissingSpecVersionError)
> Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/priyanshu.sahoo/.gem/ruby/2.7.0:/Users/priyanshu.sahoo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0', execute `gem env` for more information

As this says it cant find rspec-support 3.9.1 so i install it. Then while running it again it shows another error saying it doesn't need 3.9.1.

> You have already activated rspec-support 3.9.1, but your Gemfile requires rspec-support 3.6.0. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

This is my first time working with a rails application. Please help me out.

Comment: Hi, have you tried doing what is suggested in the error message? Prepend your command with `bundle exec` as such `bundle exec rspec`. `bundle exec` will execute the script using the gem versions specified in the Gemfile (as opposed to the ones installed globally).

Comment: Yeah that wasnt helping. Running bundle clean --force did the trick for me, turns out there's some outdated gem in my system